# What memory leaks can occur outside the view of GHC's heap profiler

Tags: linux, haskell, memory-leaks, profiling, ghc

I have a program that exhibits the behavior of a memory leak. It gradually takes up all of the systems memory until it fills all swap space and then the operating system kills it. This happens once every several days.

I have extensively profiled the heap in a manner of ways (-hy, -hm, -hc) and tried limiting heap size (-M128M) tweaked the number of generations (-G1) but no matter what I do the heap size appears constant-ish and low always (measured in kB not MB or GB). Yet when I observe the program in htop, its resident memory steadily climbs.

What this indicates to me is that the memory leak is coming from somewhere besides the GHC heap. My program makes use of dependencies, specifically Haskell's `yaml` library which wraps the C library `libyaml`, it is possible that the leak is in the number of foreign pointers it has to objects allocated by `libyaml`.

My question is threefold:

1. What places besides the GHC heap can memory leak from in a Haskell program?
2. What tools can I use to track these down?
3. What changes to my source code need to be made to avoid these types of leaks, as they seem to differ from the more commonly experienced space leaks in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly sounds like foreign pointers aren't being finalized properly. There are several possible reasons for this:

1. The underlying C library doesn't free memory properly.
2. The Haskell library doesn't set up finalization properly.
3. The `ForeignPtr` objects aren't being freed.

I think there's actually a decent chance that it's option 3. If the RTS consistently finds enough memory in the first GC generation, then it just won't bother running a major collection. Fortunately, this is the easiest to diagnose. Just have your program run `System.Memory.performGC` every so often. If that fixes it, you've found the bug and can tweak just how often you want to do that.

Another possible issue is that you could have foreign pointers lying around in long-lived thunks or other closures. Make sure you don't.

---

One particularly strong possibility when working with a wrapped C library is that the wrapper functions will return `ByteString`s whose underlying arrays were allocated by C code. So any `ByteString`s you get back from `yaml` could potentially be off-heap.

Comment: Can this be accomplished with the GC parameter `-In` that performs a GC if the program idles for a while? or is that only going to perform a minor GC.

Comment: @ProofOfKeags, that will perform a major GC if your program has been idle for long enough. By default, it's only enabled for the threaded runtime, and the default idle time is 0.3 seconds. If you're using the threaded runtime `--threaded` and your program isn't very busy, then you've probably already performed that diagnostic step and should move on to looking for stored foreign pointers. (cont)

Comment: (cont) I just remembered something: `ByteString` contains a `ForeignPointer` to the actual bytes. So any `ByteStrings` whose underlying memory was allocated by C code (e.g., in `libyaml`) will retain memory outside the Haskell heap. So look for any place you could be leaking those!

Comment: It appears to be an issue with C memory not being cleaned up. This answers my main question. Thank you.